# If exists unallowed files, show messagebox with their name

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
HashSet<string> allowedFiles = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
      "file1.dll",
      "file2.dll",
      "file3.exe"
};

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
bool containsNonAllowedFiles = directory.EnumerateFiles().Any(file => !allowedFiles.Contains(file.Name));

if (containsNonAllowedFiles == true)
{
     Message.Warning("Unallowed files found ! Please remove them."); 
     return; 
}
```

But I want to show filename, which is *unallowed*, how can I do it?

For example I have folder with these files: *file1.dll, file2.dll, file3.exe, file4.exe*, When I launch the app it must print for me Unallowed files found ! Please remove **file4.exe** and start app again. Thanks in advance

Comment: What if there are a large number of files not allowed. Do you want to show them all in a message box?

Comment: I will make Unallowed files found ! Please remove: file4.exe, file5.exe, file5.exe, etc... That's not problem, problem how to show unallowed file name? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        List<FileInfo> files = directory.GetFiles().ToList();
        List<FileInfo> unAllowed = files.FindAll(f => !allowedFiles.Contains(f.Name));

        if (unAllowed.Count > 0)
        {
            string notAllowedFiles = "";
            unAllowed.ForEach(f => notAllowedFiles += f.Name + ",");
            Message.Warning("Unallowed files found ! Please remove " + notAllowedFiles);
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the Except method from Linq to produce the list of unallowed file names.

```
var disallowedFiles = directory.EnumerateFiles()
                               .Select(fi => fi.Name)
                               .Except(allowedFiles, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: This is a much better answer, as it will give all the required files.. +1,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Where` instead of the early `Any`:

```
var nonAllowedFilesNames = directory.EnumerateFiles()
    .Select(file => file.Name)
    .Where(fileName => !allowedFiles.Contains(fileName));
if(nonAllowedFilesNames.Any())
{
     string unallowedFiles = String.Join(",", nonAllowedFilesNames);
     Message.Warning("Unallowed files found ! Please remove: " + unallowedFiles); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must get the list of unallowed files. You can do it like this :

```
List<String> nonAllowedFiles = directory.EnumerateFiles().FindAll(file => !allowedFiles.Contains(file.Name));
```

and then you can process it like this :

```
foreach (String file in nonAllowedFiles ) {
    Message.Warning("Unallowed files found ! Please remove " + file + " and start app again"); 
}
return;
```